# Want to dynamically change variable names in SAS

Tags: variables, dynamic, while-loop, sas, sas-macro

Is there a data driven way to dynamically change the variable names from one name to another where each dataset may or may not have the original variable? I want to iterate through each dataset to change the old variable (if it exists since some datasets have more variables than others) and assign it as a single new standardized variable name. How can this be accomplished in a data driven manner?

Should this be:

```
%let statement
array with do loop
Read in excel file with variable lists and rename statement old=new
macro
```

For example,

Dataset 1

```
ProvID NPI Txnmy_cd Txnmy_cd2 Spec_cd1 Spec_cd2 Spec_cd3 Spec_cd4
```

Dataset 2

```
ProvID NPI Txnmy_cd1 Txnmy_cd2 Txnmy_cd3 Txnmy_cd4 Spec_cd Spec_cd1
```

Dataset 3

```
ProvID NPI Txnmy_cd Txnmy_cd2 Txnmy_cd3 Txnmy_cd4 Spec_cd1 Spec_cd2
```

and so on...

Final Result:

Dataset 1

```
ProvID NPI Taxonomy Taxonomy2 Taxonomy3 ProvSpec1 ProvSpec2 ProvSpec3 ProvSpec4
```

Dataset 2

```
ProvID NPI Taxonomy Taxonomy2 Taxonomy3 Taxonomy4 ProvSpec1 ProvSpec2
```

Dataset 3

```
ProvID NPI Taxonomy Taxonomy2 Taxonomy3 Taxonomy4 ProvSpec1 ProvSpec2
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

The most deterministic way is to maintain a mapping table of name transformations.

Example (mapping based on final result shown in question)

```
xl_name   sas_name        based on
-------   --------        -----------
Txnmy_cd  Taxonomy        per 1 2 3
Txnmy_cd1 Taxonomy        per   2
Txnmy_cd2 Taxonomy2       per 1 2 3
Txnmy_cd3 Taxonomy3       per   2 3
Txnmy_cd4 Taxonomy4       per   2 3
Spec_cd   ProvSpec1       per   2
Spec_cd1  ProvSpec1       per 1   3
Spec_cd1  ProvSpec2       per   2     # inconsistent
Spec_cd2  ProvSpec2       per 1   3
Spec_cd3  ProvSpec3       per 1
Spec_cd4  ProvSpec4       per 1
```

First, the result examples for `sas_name` targets are inconsistent

- for taxonomy the first rename is to `Taxonomy`
- for provspec the first rename is to `ProcSpec1`

Second, the real world intrudes on a pristine mapping table

- the final result data 2 transform of `spec_cd1` to `ProvSpec2` is not consistent with the other mappings shown for data 1 and data 3.

**Real question?**

Q: Should the renames be based on variable name prefixes, and 1,2,3,4 suffix be based on order of appearance (repetition count) of suffix ?

Suppose that is the case.  Use a prefix mapping table (or format) to locate the source variables that need to be renamed with an in order numeric suffix.

Example:

```
proc format;
  value $prefix_map
  'Txnmy_cd' = ':Taxonomy'    /* : means 1st does not get 1 suffix */
  'Spec_cd'  = '#ProvSpec'    /* # means 1st does     get 1 suffix */
  other = ' '
  ;

%macro rename_per_prefix(data=);
  %local renames lib mem;

  %let syslast = &data;
  %let lib = %scan(&syslast,1,.);
  %let mem = %scan(&syslast,2,.);

  proc contents noprint data=&data out=_names_(keep=name varnum);
  data _names_;
    set _names_;

    length sas_prefix $25;
    do len = length(name) to 1 by -1 until(not missing(sas_prefix));
      sas_prefix = put(substr(name,1,len),$prefix_map.);
    end;

    if not missing(sas_prefix);
  proc sort 
    data=_names_; by sas_prefix varnum;
  data _null_;
    length renames $32767; retain renames;
    do until (no_more_candidates);
      do index = 1 by 1 until (last.sas_prefix);
        set _names_ end=no_more_candidates;
        by sas_prefix;

        if sas_prefix =: ':' then
          if index = 1 then suffix = ''; else suffix = cats(index);
        else
        if sas_prefix =: '#' then 
          suffix = cats(index);

        newname = cats(substr(sas_prefix,2),suffix);

        renames = catx(' ', renames, catx('=', name, newname));        
      end;
    end;

    call symput('renames', strip(renames));
  run;    

  %if %length(%superq(renames)) %then %do;
  proc datasets nolist lib=&lib;
    modify &mem;
    rename %superq(renames);
  %end;

  proc delete data=_names_;
  run;
%mend;

* mimic data import;
data one;
call missing(ProvID,NPI,Txnmy_cd,Txnmy_cd2,Spec_cd1,Spec_cd2,Spec_cd3,Spec_cd4);
data two;
call missing(ProvID,NPI,Txnmy_cd1,Txnmy_cd2,Txnmy_cd3,Txnmy_cd4,Spec_cd,Spec_cd1);
data three;
call missing(ProvID,NPI,Txnmy_cd,Txnmy_cd2,Txnmy_cd3,Txnmy_cd4,Spec_cd1,Spec_cd2);
run;

* perform renames;

%rename_per_prefix(data=one)
%rename_per_prefix(data=two)
%rename_per_prefix(data=three)
```

**What if**

Suppose there were consistent transformations across all Excel sources.

After importing a data set data from Excel, you can use `Proc CONTENTS` and the mapping table to programmatically generate the SAS code that performs the transforming renames.

*The mapping table and codegen become more complicated if you allow the import process to bring in variable names that require name literals to specify. (I.e. import brings in a variable named `'Provided Specimen #1'n`*

Example:

```
data name_map;
length xl_name sas_name $32;
input 
xl_name  sas_name; datalines;
Txnmy_cd  Taxonomy
Txnmy_cd1 Taxonomy
Txnmy_cd2 Taxonomy2
Txnmy_cd3 Taxonomy3
Txnmy_cd4 Taxonomy4
Spec_cd   ProvSpec1
Spec_cd1  ProvSpec1
Spec_cd2  ProvSpec2 
Spec_cd3  ProvSpec3
Spec_cd4  ProvSpec4
;

%macro rename_per_map(data=, map=name_map);
  %local renames lib mem;

  %let syslast = &data;
  %let lib = %scan(&syslast,1,.);
  %let mem = %scan(&syslast,2,.);

  proc contents noprint data=&data out=_names_(keep=name);
  proc sql noprint;
    select catx('=',xl_name,sas_name) 
    into :renames separated by ' '
    from _names_ source
    join &map    map
      on source.name = map.xl_name
    ;
  %if %length(%superq(renames)) %then %do;
  proc datasets nolist lib=&lib;
    modify &mem;
    rename %superq(renames);
  %end;
  proc delete data=_names_;
  run;
%mend;

* mimic data import;
data one;
call missing(ProvID,NPI,Txnmy_cd,Txnmy_cd2,Spec_cd1,Spec_cd2,Spec_cd3,Spec_cd4);
data two; /* tweaked to be consistent */
call missing(ProvID,NPI,Txnmy_cd1,Txnmy_cd2,Txnmy_cd3,Txnmy_cd4,Spec_cd,Spec_cd2);
data three;
call missing(ProvID,NPI,Txnmy_cd,Txnmy_cd2,Txnmy_cd3,Txnmy_cd4,Spec_cd1,Spec_cd2);
run;

* perform renames;

%rename_per_map(data=one)
%rename_per_map(data=two)
%rename_per_map(data=three)
```

Comment: To follow-up, can I automate through all 15 datasets I have with using the first code removing the inconsistency in labeling. For example, I can specify all other variables using the proc format. From there, is there a way to automate through each dataset and only hit the variables that's found? For example, can I use a call symputx &data. and for the bottom piece (*mimic data import; and *perform renames specify &data. and not call all variables. I'm attempting to automate it as much as I can without listing out variables since this is only a small subset of variables used as an example.

Comment: And if I have other separate variables such as address variables, how can I account for those up above who just change from one name to another and not account for special instances of #:

Comment: An extended discussion of possible techniques and problem situations is better handled at https://communities.sas.com/ Programming discussion board.